# React Use Query and Jest

Tags: next.js, jestjs

I'm trying to test my nextjs app with Jest but according to [this example](https://www.js-howto.com/how-to-test-infinite-query-with-jest-and-react-testing-library-part-2/) , I have to tell Axios to  use node adapter while running in testing mode but for mome reason I'm getting this error.

**jest.setup.js**

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');
```

**index.test.js**

```
const mockedUseRoomsQuery = useRoomsQuery;
jest.mock("../__mocks__/roomMockData.js");

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: false,
    },
  },
});
const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    {children}
  </QueryClientProvider>
);



describe("Fetch all rooms", () => {
  it("fetches all rooms", async () => {
    nock("https://63b29d465901da0ab368e025.mockapi.io", {
      reqheaders: { "app-id": () => true },
    })
      .persist()
      .get("/api/v1/rooms")
      .reply(200, roomData);
    const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useRoomsQuery(), { wrapper });
    await waitFor(() => result.current.isSuccess);
    console.log("data returned", result.current);
  }, 10000);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You are using both commonjs and es6 syntax for importing dependancies. You use ``import`` and then for the adapter you use ``require``. Stick to one, it seems like your package.json is configured to use es modules, [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/commonjs-vs-es-modules-node-js/) is more info on this topic.